# React Native Typescript navigation not working

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a new react native expo project with typescript and I'm trying to setup navigation through React Native's TS docs but nothing is showing when I run I simulate it.

I have the following super simple boilerplate:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { RootStackParamList } from "./types";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

This is my RootStackParamList:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  ReactQuiz: undefined;
};
```

And my homepage:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

And lastly my package.json where I think the problem is:

```
{
  "name": "trivia",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "expo": "~49.0.7",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The compiler was telling me that it could have something to do with having multiple navigation dependencies installed, but this is straight from the docs. I need to use the navigationContainer (I get an error otherwise) and I need both the other dependencies for TS.

If I'm doing something very wrong, someone do tell.

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing is wrong with your code but it could be **instant problem** caused by **Hot Reload**. Just use this code and reload your application. It should be fixed but if it is not then maybe you can specify the problem with output. We can help you.

Comment: Tried reloading as well and re-created the project using same code, still nothing

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the problem? It could be different.